# Why console.log displays incorrect object's values?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

I don't understand why `console.log` displays that `d1` contains `[100,200,300]` before I even introduced these numbers. Regular `for loop` displays internals of `d1` correctly though. Can someone please explain this behavior/bug of `console.log` in Google Chrome?
https://jsfiddle.net/ZSvyt/

```
var container = {};
container["0"] = [10, 20, 30];
var d1 = container;

console.log('before console.log');
console.log(d1); // <--- IT DISPLAYS [100, 200, 300]. WHY?

// before for loop
console.log('before for loop');
for (var i = 0; i < d1["0"].length; i++) {
    console.log(d1["0"][i]);
}

container["0"] = [100, 200, 300];

console.log('after console.log');
console.log(d1);

// after for loop
console.log('after for loop');
for (var i = 0; i < d1["0"].length; i++) {
    console.log(d1["0"][i]);
}
```

Output:

```
before console.log
Object {
    0: Array[3]
}
0: Array[3] 
0: 100
1: 200
2: 300 

before for loop
10
20
30

after console.log
Object {
    0: Array[3]
}
0: Array[3] 
0: 100
1: 200
2: 300

after for loop
100
200
300
```

Comment: This will sometimes happen with nested _Objects_ because the console's lookup can happen after the reference has been changed. If it's important it's exact, use _JSON_

Comment: this screwed me up so hard.. at least now I know

Answer (score 9, accepted):

that's because what is in the console is the reference of `dt` not a copy.

you can copy  the object and log it (the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object) ).

or you can log the string that represents it using `JSON.stringify`.

`console.log( JSON.stringify(dt) );` will print it as string.

Also if you are using `lodash` then you can use `console.log(_.cloneDeep(dt))` to clone and log the correct values inside the object at that very moment.